# If a user wants to emulate some of one language's functionality in another, should the question be tagged with both languages?

Tags: discussion, tags

I personally mainly browse the Ruby tag when looking for questions to answer. A lot of times I've seen people saying "I want to emulate some part of Ruby's functionality in another language". I don't think it's really a question about Ruby, and I'm tempted to remove the ruby tag. Would this be the right thing to do?

Comment: Got an example?  These questions are frequently XY-problems, which may benefit *more* from the OP actually explaining what problem they're having.

Comment: @Makoto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442016/how-to-easily-make-custom-stream-class-in-java-like-with-ruby-enumerable